# Why iterating over total no of edges causing infinite or finitely many loop unwindings?

Tags: c, infinite-loop, cbmc

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define N 6
#define M 10

typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

unsigned int nondet_uint();  

typedef unsigned __CPROVER_bitvector[M] bitvector; 

unsigned int zeroTon(unsigned int n) {
   unsigned int result = nondet_uint();
   __CPROVER_assume(result >=0 && result <=n);
   return result ;
};


//Constrine the value between 0 and 1
unsigned int  nondet (){  
  unsigned int num = nondet_uint();
  __CPROVER_assume( num>= 0 && num  <= 1);
  return num;
}; 

void main() {
   unsigned int pos , i, j, k;

   unsigned int len = 0;
   bool Ch , Ck , C0 ;

  bitvector compartment1 , compartment2 , compartment3 , compartment4, compartment5, compartment6;
bitvector nodes[N] = {compartment1, compartment2, compartment3, compartment4, compartment5, compartment6};


// Represent the graph with given topology 
unsigned int graph[N][N];

for(i=0;i <N; i++) {
    for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
        graph[i][j] = nondet();
    }
}



unsigned int p[N] ;
unsigned int ticks;


   //Make sure that graph is one connected  : just find one hamiltonian cycle 
   //make sure elements are in between node no's and all are distinct

for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
    p[i] = zeroTon(5);
}

for(i=0; i <N; i++) {
     for(j=0; (j<N) && (j!=i) ; j++) {    
    if( p[i] != p[j]){
            C1 = C1 && 1;
        }
        else {
            C1 = C1 && 0;
        }

     }
}

 //hamiltonian One exists 
 for(i=0;i<N-1;i++) {
    if( graph[p[i]][p[i+1]] == 1) {
       Ch = Ch && 1;
    }
   else {
       Ch = Ch && 0;
   }
  }

 len =0;
 for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
   for(j=0;j<N; j++){
          if (graph[i][j] == 1) {
              len = len + 1;
          }
    }
  }

  //THIS IS GOING IN INFINITE LOOP ?? WHY ?? 
  for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
   printf("i'm a disco dancer ");

  }
  __CPROVER_assert(!(Ch && C1) , "Graph has an ham path");
}
```

I'm only trying to get a graph that of Total nodes 6 that has a Hamiltonian path. That works well with above code. But when i try to use len i.e total no.of edges i'm getting infinite unwinding in cbmc run .

The above code works well unless i iterate using len . The cbmc run going into infinite unwinding ?? Can anyone explains that.

Comment: great Debug msg.. have you tried printing `len`? what's its value?

Comment: Yes i did . That's why i first just calculate total edges and just printed the same. No problems whatsoever. i.e if i delete last for loop and just print len everything is fine. I don't understand that max len could be just  (n * n-1) but why its taking infinite unwindings ?

Comment: `0<= graph[i][j] <= 1` should be `0 == graph[i][j] || graph[i][j] == 1`.

Comment: @mch that can't be a problem.. since at most len could never go past `n * n-1`

Comment: How did that helps ?? graph[i][j] is unsigned int which can be between 0 and 1 that means zero or one. But yes your representation is far better.

Comment: @user2754673 I am not sure.. but can you try printing inside `len = len + 1;` does it print finite numbers

Comment: @user2754673 put this `printf("%d",len);` before `len = len + 1;`.. and try using an increment operator `len++;`

Comment: no prob. If i delete the last for loop and try to print len +1  each time. Starting with zero its printing 1...32. and len counts turns out to be 32 after the print.

Comment: @Minato no change , I think you guys are not targeting the prob. This problem happened as i turned the graph as input to any arbitrary graph.  i thought this might be caused due to it might be constraining all the graphs of nodes 6 but i then changed the total nodes to 2 but still same prob, something going under cbmc hood ?

Comment: The problem could be.. Though I am not sure.. but some how the first/sign bit is being set in the `len` causing it to go berserk..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95412/discussion-between-user2754673-and-minato).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Not sure about the policy of stack-overflow but in order to clarify the issue i'm posting an answer that was posted by Martin of oxford university on CBMC support forum.

> The above code works well unless i iterate using len . The cbmc run 
>    going into infinite loop ?? Can anyone explains that.
>
> Short answer : Yes, it is expected, use --unwind
>
> Long answer : CBMC's detection of loop bounds is relatively simple; it 
>   will only stop unwinding a loop (without a loop unwind limit) if the 
>   branch condition can be statically simplified to false during symbolic 
>   execution.
>
> Because the values of graph are non-deterministic, so the value of len 
>   will be non-deterministic.  Ofcourse we know from the way the rest of 
>   the code works that len <= N*N but this cannot be obtained by 
>   simplification alone, thus CBMC does not 'realise' this and so the loop 
>   unwinding will not terminate by itself.
>
> Why don't we make the bound detection smarter?  Say, track intervals for 
>   variables?  We could but unless you have a complete decision procedure 
>   there, you will always find cases like this.  If you put a complete 
>   decision procedure there you are either doing path-based symbolic 
>   execution, which is what our symex tool does, or you are doing 
>   incremental BMC (we have tools available for this, they may be merged 
>   into the next version of CBMC), depending on if you are deciding on 
>   unwinding and assertions separately or together.

thanks all for helping.

Comment: The only thing that was puzzling me was the max value that len could pick is (n * n-1) so why infinite unwiding !